# In Microsoft Word, is there a way to assign particular Bullet Styles automatically to a Heading Style through the Design Features (Themes and Styles)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, themes, styles

**What?** My goal here is to have Microsoft Word automatically adjust the Bullet List Style in a conditional manner, where the condition is the specific heading style (i.e., heading 1, heading 2, heading 3, etc.) that is used.

**How?** I am fine with a VB script implementation, but I am wondering if such a goal can be achieved using the plain vanilla Microsoft Word features (what's already there). Please note that the color of the font and the bullets vary depending on the heading they are under.

**Summary Question**: style assignment selection contingent upon Heading Style?

Please see image below for an example of what I mean above.

[image: Example of what I wish to achieve on Microsoft Word: Bullet List Styles contingent upon Heading]

Comment: This will require "Bullet List 2" to be defined as two styles : first and following lines.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Harry. May you please elaborate on this?

Comment: See Shauna Kelly's page on  bullets: http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html This assigns bullets to particular styles in a multilevel list. Such a list can be saved in a template or even a [Quick] Style Set. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-style-sets-and-word-themes-in-microsoft-word/444d4195-a28a-43bb-b035-facd84f7bd44